# Monorepo Typescript React application module not found when using docker-compose

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose

I have a monorepo for react application. The `shared/types.ts` contains all the types and are shared between the `frontend` and the `backend` folder. I want to make the `shared/types.ts` to be reflecting changes in the Docker containers when I have make changes to the file and I don't want to rebuild it everytime I change the file. I have configured the shared folder in the `tsconfig.json` in the `frontend` and `backend` respectively by using this:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
  "@shared/*": [
    "../shared/*"
  ]
}
```

However, when I used `docker-compose` to run my application, it keeps saying that `@shared/types` is not found.

This is the following structure for my project:

```
|
├── frontend
|    ├── tsconfig.json
|    ├── Dockerfile
├── backend
|    ├── tsconfig.json
|    ├── Dockerfile
├── shared
|    ├── types.ts
├── docker-compose.yml
```

This is my following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./backend/Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/backend/node_modules
      - ./backend:/usr/src/backend/
      - ./shared:/usr/src/shared/
  frontend:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./frontend/Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/frontend/node_modules
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/frontend/
      - ./shared:/usr/src/shared/
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/backend
RUN chown node /usr/src/backend

USER node
WORKDIR /usr/src/backend

COPY --chown=node:node ./backend/package.json ./
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

May I know how to get the frontend and backend container to recognize the `shared` folder? Many thanks in advance!